# How to correctly number rows in the indicated column in the table

Tags: php

How to correctly number rows in the indicated column in the table

```
<?php
    require_once('conect.php');
    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabelatestowa ORDER BY pkt DESC");
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++);
    $numbers_rows = 1; {
?>              
    <tr>
      <td><label><?php echo $row['id']; ?></label></td>
      <td><label><?php echo ++$number_rows;?>  </label></td>
      <td><label><?php echo $row['name']; ?></label></td>
      <td><label><?php echo $row['pkt']; ?></label></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `$numbers_rows = 1;` should be before `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished by doing `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` and looping over it with `foreach`. This way you don't have to worry about manually setting or incrementing a counter:

```
<?php
            require_once('conect.php');
            $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabelatestowa ORDER BY pkt DESC");
            $result->execute();
            $results = $result->fetchAll();
            foreach ($results as $index => $row) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                  <td><label><?php echo $row['id']; ?></label></td>
                  <td><label><?php echo ($index + 1);?>  </label></td>
                  <td><label><?php echo $row['name']; ?></label></td>
                  <td><label><?php echo $row['pkt']; ?></label></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just how to make the first row = 1 and not 0. $index = 1 not work

Comment: @Marianna If you're echoing `$index +1` like I have it here, the first row will be 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing the ';' at the end of for loop and shifting the $numbers_rows = 1; before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this,seems issue with for loop format and numbers_rows should before loop

```
<?php
            require_once('conect.php');
            $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabelatestowa ORDER BY pkt DESC");
            $result->execute();
            $numbers_rows = 1;
            for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
             {
        ?>              
            <tr>
                  <td><label><?php echo $row['id']; ?></label></td>
                  <td><label><?php echo ++$number_rows;?>  </label></td>
                  <td><label><?php echo $row['name']; ?></label></td>
                  <td><label><?php echo $row['pkt']; ?></label></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The general point of the other answers is correct about moving the initialisation of the variable outside the loop and correcting where the { goes.

Generally it's written like Alive to Die pointed out with a `while()` loop...

```
$numbers_rows = 1;
while($row = $result->fetch()){
```

The one thing I wanted to add was your `echo` of the value is using a pre increment (add 1 then use the value), so setting the value to 1 before the loop will mean the first value printed will be 2.

Change the echo to...

```
echo $number_rows++;
```

to ensure it starts with 1.